# How can I get the size of a directory on iOS 10.3 with APFS?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager, apfs

One of the benefits of APFS announced at WWDC 2016 was the ability to get the size of a directory very quickly, instead of having to walk the whole folder structure. The demo given was the Get Info window in Finder not having to asynchronously calculate the size of a directory.

I have an iOS app where I need to display the file size of a directory. Right now I do it recursively, summing up the sizes of all the files in all the subdirectories. But now that APFS has shipped with iOS 10.3, I'd like to take advantage of the new file system to do it much more efficiently. Is there an API for this somewhere? I don't see it referenced in the [`NSFileManager` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager). Right now I use [`attributesOfItemAtPath`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager/1410452-attributesofitematpath?language=objc) and the `NSFileSize` key.

Comment: APFS should be transparent at that level as far as I know. do you wanna use things like low-level functions?

Comment: @MertBuran it makes sense for the file system would be transparent, but it must affect the behavior of some API somewhere. Is that just at the low level?

Comment: if it is transparent that means filesystem API doesn't change, otherwise it wouldn't be transparent :) there is some changes in `diskutil`'s API, now you have `diskutil apfs` command, but i guess there won't be a change in `NSFileManager` level. if APFS optimizes file size calculation, you already have it.

Comment: @MertBuran my understanding from the WWDC presentation was that the size of the folder is actually stored with the folder. So I guess the question becomes how to correctly ask a folder for its size?

Comment: @TomHamming my first guess would be your current approach, looking up that value on the directory itself instead of recursively scanning. Does that not work?

Comment: @TomHarrington not on cursory experimentation. I got tens of kilobytes on a directory I know is over 100 MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this in the APFS lab at WWDC 2018, and it would be done via an API called `dirstat_np`, but it's currently a private API and not available for public use. It may be offered at some point as a public API but no promises. I'm going to file a radar.

Comment: What's the Radar number? Did you post it to Open Radar?

Comment: https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1244.1.7/libdarwin/dirstat.h